# passing an additional parameter to a function when function is called via event i.e :Connect()

Tags: oop, lua, roblox

I'm trying to convert my nameless function to work better using OOP and having some difficulty as I relied on a certain scope. Any suggestions, old and new code below:

OLD CODE - WORKS

```lua
for _,portal in pairs(script.Parent:GetChildren())do
    if portal:IsA("Script") then continue end
    portal.Touched:Connect(function(part)
        local HRP = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        if not HRP then return end
        local DestinationName = portal:FindFirstChildOfClass("Attachment").Name
        local Destination = script.Parent:FindFirstChild(DestinationName):FindFirstChild(portal.Name)
        HRP.CFrame = Destination.WorldCFrame
    end)
end
```

NEW CODE - ERRORS OBVS

```lua
local function portalTouched(part,portal)
    local HRP = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    if not HRP then return end
    local DestinationName = portal:FindFirstChildOfClass("Attachment").Name
    local Destination = script.Parent:FindFirstChild(DestinationName):FindFirstChild(portal.Name)
    HRP.CFrame = Destination.WorldCFrame
end

for _,portal in pairs(script.Parent:GetChildren())do
    if portal:IsA("Script") then continue end
    portal.Touched:Connect(portalTouched(portal))
end
```

Problem with connecting functions to events is you cant pass any additional parameters,
How can I get around this scope issue? Any and all suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a higher-order function that is called with `portal` and then returns a function which can use the parameter from the enclosing function:

```lua
local function portalTouched(portal)
    return function(part)
        -- We can use portal in this function
        local HRP = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        if not HRP then return end
        local DestinationName = portal:FindFirstChildOfClass("Attachment").Name
        local Destination = script.Parent:FindFirstChild(DestinationName):FindFirstChild(portal.Name)
        HRP.CFrame = Destination.WorldCFrame
    end
end

for _,portal in pairs(script.Parent:GetChildren())do
    if portal:IsA("Script") then continue end
    portal.Touched:Connect(portalTouched(portal))
end
```

Comment: Never heard of that method before, is that better practice? Would you also mind explaining how it works a little further as I didn't realise you could parse additional parameters with Connect(function)

Comment: Well it's more of a preference than a question or practice, you can go either way depending on whether you want an anonymous function or a short concise line as above.

Comment: The additional parameters aren't actually being passed from the connection, what we do is we exploit closure. Variables from enclosing functions are exposed to inner functions, we use this to provide variables without receiving the variables as parameters.  

Since we need to give the event a function and we can't mess with parameters, we manipulate its environment, we do this with a higher-order function - a function that takes or gives a function. By using such a function, we're able introduce `portal` to the returned anonymous function without it being a parameter of the returned function